# PHP Variable in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which is not working

```
  <body>
<?php $outerSql = mysql_query("select * from gree_menu"); ?>
<ul>
  <?php
    while($outerRow = mysql_fetch_array($outerSql)) {
      $outerMenu = $outerRow['menu_name'];
      $outerId = $outerRow['menu_id'];
    ?>
      <li>
        <?=$outerMenu; ?>
        <?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id = {$outerID}");?>

        <ul>
          <?php

            while($innerRow = mysql_fetch_array($innerSql)) {
              $innerMenu = $innerRow['prod_name'];
          ?>
            <li><?= $innerMenu;?></li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>

</ul>
```

The line that is causing me trouble is

```
 <?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id = {$outerID}");?>
```

If i give the query as

```
 <?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id = 7");?>
```

it works fine. But i want it to be dynamic. Valid values for menu_id are 7, 8, 9

Please help

Comment: You made a typo, it should be `outerID`, not `outerId`. PHP is case sensitive. I recommend using copy/paste for variable names, or using a text editor that has autocomplete (try out Sublime Text or Eclipse). Using either copy/paste or autocomplete will save you time and frustration by reducing typos like this one.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

`<?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id =".{$outerID});?>`

Answer (score 2):

Your have typo in outerID, not outerId as mentioned by @Abhi Beckert.

```
$outerId = $outerRow['menu_id'];
```

You used `$outerID` in query. So I don't think your query have errors. Correct the typo and try again.

If you like to change the query try like below

```
$innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm 
          INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id
          WHERE gm.menu_id = ".$outerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one

```
 <?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id = ".$outerID."");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $innerSql = mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id WHERE gm.menu_id = ".$outerID);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT sp.* FROM gree_menu gm 
INNER JOIN silicon_prod sp ON gm.menu_id = sp.menu_parent_id 
WHERE gm.menu_id =$outerID");
```